# Magento Getting error while importing products

Tags: php, mysql, magento, phpmyadmin, magento-1.4

I am facing a problem while `importing products` in `magento`.
Actually I have one multi website Magento project.
When I start to import products using `magento`'s default import functionality, I am getting this type of error

```
"mysql error 1205 lock wait timeout exceeded try restarting transaction."
```

and sometimes products are imported completely but it takes lot's of time for `re-indexing`.

So Has anyone of you are faced this kind of problem and if yes then what to do to solve this type of problem?

- I also try to `re-indexing` using **SSH** also but still facing this
  kinds of error.

Hope I get response very soon.

[image]

Comment: Is there any one here who have knowledge about magento and this types of error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have some record lock problems with your MySQL server. Try restarting it : it automatically runs a corruption check on all tables. Tell us if this solves your problem !

Comment: are you also facing this type of problem?

Comment: I used to have this type of problem when the server was overloaded with too many connections, but never because of any corruption on tables. But this helped me to figure out about your problem (and also Google helped me). Did you try restarting your sql daemon ?